# Modelling of 6xPWM for BLDC

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm looking to model 6xPWM signals to control a BLDC in Matlab/Simulink. My idea is to utilise the additional "dead-time" that you get with 6xPWM to hopefully better control the motor.

However, I'm unsure as how exactly to model the dead-time seen in 6xPWM? There is little to no literature on this. Would it be as simple as:

Dead_Time = Period - ON_Time - OFF_Time (?)

Apologies if it's very obvious I'm just a bit unsure on how to best model this dead-time!

Thanks

Comment: esp32 SoC has a BLDC/DC Motor Control PWM (MCPWM) controller which has rather low level API, including dead time setting and other goodies:  https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/mcpwm.html. BTW, dead time is to avoid frying the H-bridges, not just for "better control".

Comment: No it would not be that simple. With 6 PWMs, I would guess you are using 2 per half-bridge, one for its high side and the other for its low side. The dead time is the time when both PWM signals are off (and if they are ever both on at once, you have destroyed your motor controller)